# merging excel files into one but some columns are flipped

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, database, merge

I have about 30 excel files, where I need to merge all like the following:

**Excel file 1:**

*ID | Lat | Long | Name*

1  | 33.3| 35.4 | X

...

**Excel File 2:**

*ID | Long | Lat | Name | Additional_Field*

3  | 36.4 | 34.2| XYZ | Yes

**As you see, there is common columns in each file, and some extra fields in the other files, and some columns are flipped in some file, like excel file 2 where long column  is before lat column**

The result I want is the following:

ID | Lat | Long | Name

...data..

Where I don't want the additional fields that it doesn't exist in the other files.

Is there a way to do that ? I need to merge thousands of rows, so I can add them into database for some data management tasks.

Comment: Yes there is a way but what did you try? There is no point us giving suggesting if you've already tried it

Comment: Yes. I tried some functions like VLOOKUPS, but VLOOkUPS join according to a common value. And I don't want that

Comment: I don't understand why you've tagged with database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a good job for [Power Query](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39379).

1. Ensure all of your tables are Excel Tables `Insert>Tables>Table`.
2. Ensure all of your tables have the same column names-capitalization is important, but order isn't.
3. Load each table into Power Query `Excel Data>From Table`
4. Perform an [Append Query](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Append-queries-Power-Query-e42ca582-4f62-4a43-b37f-99e2b2a4813a) including each table, as [discussed here](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/How-to-union-or-append-tables-with-different-column-order/td-p/47536).
5. Let Power Query reorder the columns and merge the info into one table for you.